# How to calculate Website Bandwidth?

Tags: web-hosting, bandwidth

I'm already hosting my site, and looking for another host. So I need to know how much bandwidth my website is using.

On my current host I can see only following bandwidth related data:

Outbound traffic (24 hours)

- **Maximum** 801kb/s
- **Average** 398kb/s

I want to know how many Gb/month I need.

Comment: Next time host your site with one of the millions webhosting service offering cPanel, and cPanel itself will tell you the monthly bandwidth your are consuming with an easy to read graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

398 (kb/sec) * 60 (sec/min) * 60 (min/hour) * 24 (hours/day) * 30 (days/month) / (8 (bits/byte)) / (1024 KB/MB)  / (1024 MB/GB) = 123 GB/Month

Answer (score 1):

Please check detailed bandwidth statistics via your control panel and you will know all the details regarding this.

Moreover, the access logs will give you all the details regarding the ip addresses from which the site was accessed.

Answer (score 0):

For an ordinary Joomla or Wordpress site, you won't need more than 50 GB of traffic per month. That is proved. You can test some hosting plan somewhere and see via Cpanel stats how much traffic is needed for your site.